# Make users understand a deep link is both for download and in app use

Tags: user-behavior

I am using deep links in my app for joining to a group,and are the main way for it.
I have worked hard to make the links redirect to store if app is not installed and if installed join the user to the group.
The problem is that users don’t understand that the links are both for download and joining, and share instead of a single link, a link for the App Store, google play and for joining.

How can I make users understand this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with that solution is that it serves two very different needs. If it's a plain link, as for example "http://foo.bar/joingroup_x", there isn't much you can do. Either you rename the last part of the url so it's clear, that by hitting that link you're going to join a group or install the app (like "http://foo.bar/install_app_and_join_group") or you place a description somewhere near that link which must be styled in a way that the user would notice it.
Another way could be to use a button with a descriptive label on it.

Both not nice solutions though but you need to somehow to communicate the two different intents.

I don't know your motivation to implement it that way, but I think you wanted to lower the effort needed to join the App. You may consider to split those two functions again, as it seems that the built-in install function isn't really needed and maybe don't really fullfill its function.

Answer (score 1):

You should inform user about:

"What will happened after click a button"

The possibilities I see:

1. 2 Buttons (one for specified action)
2. Above button you can add paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

"Join Group on APP."

If they have the app, it opens and works.

If they don't have the app, a popup will appear and say "Install APP to join group."

Alternative, if you aren't getting the clicks:

- Primary button "Join Group on APP."
- Secondary/Text button "Don't have APP?
  Download here."

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad user experience, if one link can perform more than one action. Use two separate link for these two functions.

1. Provide the possibility to join groups via both web and mobile applications. Then in the web application you would provide 2 links: one for joining groups and one for insralling the app.
2. Allow joining groups via the app only. Then provide a single link and it should have a single function - downloading the app. Then explain users, that to join a group they should install the app first.